# Is it well-defined behavior to return a vector of const char*, filled inside a function

Tags: c++, stdvector, c-strings

I am currently learning vulkan. In one of the tutorials I saw a function which roughly does the following:

```
#define SOMESTRING "Hello World!"

std::vector<const char*> buildVector() {
    std::vector<const char*> vec;
    vec.push_back(SOMESTRING);
    return vec;
}
```

When I saw this, I was wondering: is this defined behavior? Isn't the content of the string `"Hello World!"` located on the stack and thus is invalid once the function returns? If this is undefined behavior, what would be the correct way to do this? Unfortunately, using `std::string` is not an option because of the vulkan API.

Comment: Same as `const char* stuff() { return SOMESTRING; }`. The vector doesn't do anything magical here.

Comment: String literals are lvalues with static storage duration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, because `SOMESTRING`'s scope (viz. value represented by that macro) belongs to [static storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/storage-of-string-literals?view=msvc-170), i.e. string literals have full lifetime of the program execution. And that is your case here.

---

Here are various scenarios:

- `#define SOMESTRING "Hello World!"`
  --> OK. String literals are stored in static storage & hence their lifetime is from program's beginning till end
- `const char* SOMESTRING = "Hello World!"`
  --> OK. Same as above.
- `char SOMESTRING[] = "Hello World!";`
  --> OK, iff it's declared in a `static` or `extern` scopes.
  --> BAD, if this array is declared within a function as a non-static.
- `char* SOMESTRING = new char[X]; strncpy(SOMESTRING, "Hello World!", N);`
  --> OK, because the string's storage is now in free store (i.e. heap) & will remain so until it's deleted. The catch is that, the strings stored in `vector` have to be freed up later to prevent memory leak.

BTW, `std::vector` doesn't influence the define/undefine-ness of the behaviour; In this case here it depends on the C-style string literals only as illustrated above.

Comment: `SOMESTRING` doesn't have a "scope". It's a macro, whose expansion is a literal, not a name. Only names have scopes. And "full lifetime" isn't a type of lifetime in C++.